# PHP Regex that matches regular, valid URLs only

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm looking for a regex that matches valid, online URLs only.

For example:

```
exmaple.com
http://exmaple.com
https://exmaple.com
www.exmaple.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

And special domains and extensions like:

```
t.co
example.deals
sh.party
```

And so on, but won't match all the complicated stuff like `ftp`, `get` queries or URLs like `2.3.3.1`.

I've been using `'#(www\.|https?://)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,4}\S*#i'` but It detects **dates**, for example `3.3.2017`.

I need this becuase I apply `get_headers` to every found URL, and when I do `get_headers` for invalid URLs like a date, I get:

`get_headers(http://03.03.2017): failed to open stream: Connection timed out`

**TL;DR:** I'm looking for a Regex that matches *only* URLs you can apply `get_headers()` on.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are there any top level domains containing numbers? And btw 'deals' has five chrs.

Comment: @JosefScript looks like there is no problem with domains like `12345.com` although i'm pretty sure there isn't any only numerical extension.

Comment: A regex can't tell an `online URL`, it can only match a pattern. Matching the pattern of a domain is also going to be hard, is `chris.inc` a company name or a domain?

Comment: @Aviel Shomron: Top level is the 'com' part. Is there anything like 'company.123'?

Answer (score 2):

I would say Regex is not the best solution for checking valid URL. It would be better to use [FILTER_VALIDATE_URL](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/filter_validate_url.asp):

```
<?php
 $url = "https://www.w3schools.com";

 if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
   echo("$url is a valid URL");
 } else {
   echo("$url is not a valid URL");
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: if it is IP address you could validate using FILTER_VALIDATE_IP. Using both you will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: not exactly, `23.2017` is not an IP because 2017 is bigger than 255. In my code I need to detect only urls because when you give anything else to `get_headers()` the connection times out and it lags the website.

Comment: I see that you seem to be afraid that `get_headers` will time out. You will not avoid this issue -> if you have `somethingthatdoesnotexist.com` your expected code will consider it ok, and you will *still* get a time-out. So you are jumping trough hoops to avoid having the 'special' case of `23.2017` return false, but for each of those examples there are a lot of examples that you find 'valid' but also do not exist. I would say: just use the `filter_validate_url`, it's not worth it to try and remove the arbitrary 'worse' urls

Answer (score 1):

```
#(https?:\/\/)?([a-z0-9_~-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,5}(\/\S*)?#i
```

EDIT: Third try: Optional http or https at start. After that follows at least one domain name and a dot, then a top-level domain of 2-5 letters and an optional tail of a backslash and additional non-space characters.

Comment: Looks good but the thing is that this regex accepts urls like `example.com:)` which is a problem for `get_headers` since this URL is invalid.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to what [LinkifyJS](http://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/) does, but in PHP. I couldn't find its regex from the source code.